# create Kibana index pattern can match on 2 different index

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I would like to do an Kibana index pattern able to match with this index :
[image]

I would like something work like this : network* OR system*

Is it possible ?

Thx for your help :)
Hugo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you can simply comma-separate them

```
network*,system*
```